How to set up Cohere SDK for Ojet project
I would like to use Cohere SDK in a TypeScript Ojet project but I just can't use the JS code runtime.
This is how the SDK looks like after npm install (under node_modules)

In the Ojet project the path mapping looks like this:

This is how the libs folder looks like after building the project.

And this is the error I got runtime.

Should I map to another file/folder?
Thank you.
